# How to reload iCarousel with animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, icarousel

I tried to find a way of reloading the iCarousel with animations. 
Something like:

```
[self.carousel reloadDataAnimated:YES] // ObjC
self.carousel!.reloadData(animated: true) // Swift
```

I looked into the header and it looks like the control does not support this. Does anyone know how can I achieve a carousel reload with animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way of doing this using `transitionWithView` method. Works like a charm. Carousel's content is reloaded with a nice cross dissolve animation. Here is the code:

#### Swift

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.carousel!,
                          duration: 0.35,
                          options: .TransitionCrossDissolve,
                          animations: { () -> Void in

                              self.carousel!.reloadData()
                          },
                          completion:nil)
```

#### ObjC

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.carousel
                  duration:0.35f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^(void)
 {
      [self.carousel reloadData];
 }
                completion:nil];
```

Comment: The above code didn't work for me in Swift 4.1 as given below:
`UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                self.reloadData()
            }, completion: nil)`


Where **self** is subclass of *iCarousel*.

Can you please pin point what I am doing wrong?